# Asp.Net MVC don't show Index action in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller

I would like that the Index action doesn't appear in the url.

For example, I would like to see

www.mywebsite.com/MyController/1

instead of

www.mywebsite.com/MyController/Index/1

Is there something special I have to do in the Html.ActionLink tag or in the global.aspx file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this for your routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Index",
    "/{controller}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

It sets the action to the default of "Index"

Comment: I am also trying to acheive this, but am getting the following error in MVC 2: The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

yes you can by modifying your route like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",                                              // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "MyController", action = "Index", id = 1 }  // Parameter defaults
            );
```